# how to send dynamically changed parameter from one jsp page to another jsp page?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have two jsp pages

in one.jsp

```
 <input type="text" name="<%=i%>"  id="<%=i%>" property="na" value="">
```

I have to send this name="<%=i%>" i value to another jsp page. two.jsp

```
<table align="center" border="1">
        <tr>

            <td class="heading" align="center" >Programme Code</td>
            <td class="heading" align="center">Programme Name</td>
            <td class="heading" align="center" ></td>
            </tr>
            <% 
                    int i;
                    for(i=0;i<11;i++)
             {
            %>
            <tr>

                <td><input type="text" name="prgmid"  id="" size="10" value=""> </td> 

                <td><input type="text" name="<%=i%>"  id="1<%=i%>" value=""> </td>
               <td><a href="programme_mang_upload.jsp?param1=<%=i%>"> Upload </a></td>

           </tr> 
            <% } %>

    </table>
```

@when I click on upload button or link the values in the text box has to send to two.jsp@

Thank you.

Comment: set it as attribute and forward it using RequestDispatcher... better way is you do it via servlet to preserve the MVC flow

Comment: Use JQuery to get value of each element.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. You can set that value in url parameter while calling another jsp page, Either you can do this via javascript Or simply generate link on First jsp to second jsp with this value as parameter, like this

`<a href="two.jsp?param1=<%=i%>"> link to 2nd jsp </a>`

and catch param1 in second jsp file by request.getParameter("param1") and you can use it.

Comment: please post your code. make sure <%=i%> is printing value. it should work with ease. if you getting url like two.jsp?param1=10  then at two.jsp <% request.getParameter("param1").toString() %>  will print 10.

Comment: sir,I have to send text box values to two.jsp

Comment: Submit your form on One.jsp with get method with two.jsp as your action url.